# how to send mouse/keyboard inputs over the network to another peer?

Tags: java, middleware

how would you go about sending mouse/keyboard inputs from a computer, which are executed to another computer over a network?

so it would be like remote controlling the other computer by sending out raw mouse/keyboard inputs.

is there a middleware that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`Robot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) on the remote computer. Communicate using [sockets](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/).